# Trying to make a rename feature for a list/table

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html, meteor

I want the user to be able to change the name of a list/table

```
<div class="col-md-6">
    <form method="post">
      <h1>
        <b>
          <input type="text" value="Group" id="groupName">
        </b>
      </h1>
          <input type="submit" value="Change Name">
    </form>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/bqgqhxs2/
i only put up the bare minimum code to hopefully get my point across.

i have a "hidden" text box and a submit button and i want the value that the user inputs into the text box to become the new value preferably without having to reload the page.

how would i go about implementing that? or is what I'm asking for even possible?

also if anyone has any other suggestions for a "rename" feature I'm all ears, the overall project is going to be implemented into meteor so if someone has a meteor solution that would be great but I'm only worrying about one problem at a time.

Comment: _"want the user to be able to change the name of a list/table"_ No "list" or "table" appear at `html` at Question ?

Comment: I don't see a hidden text box.  I see a textbox that doesn't have a border...  Where should the value of that textbox update?

Comment: Very possible specially with angularJS

Comment: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/input/input%5Btext%5D

Comment: @Taplar sorry by hidden i meant a text box that i don't want to make obvious that it is a text box. and i want that text box to update its own value if such a thing is possible, for example the value is group but i want the user to change that value by typing into the textbox and pressing the submit button.

Comment: Uh, the act of the user changing the text of the input DOES change it's value.  That's what it's value is...  If your thinking it is not because your viewing the page source and you don't see it changing, then that is not an issue.  The html is used to load the elements into the DOM.  Changes to the input are reflected in the DOM and that is where the values will come from if you submit the form.  Not from the original html source.

Comment: "box to update its own value if such a thing is possible"  - the value of the input is whatever is typed into the input. It is updated . Really not sure what you are asking

Comment: @Cory i was looking at it from the wrong side, it seems what i was asking for is already being done i just didn't realize it because i wasn't actually seeing it when i hit submit the page would load and the group value would remain so i just assumed there was some kind of error on my part.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `blur` method to take the new name typed into the input.

```
 $("#groupName").on( "blur", function() {
    //change the id here
   $("table").attr("id", $(this).val() )
    //or the value of an element
   $("table").attr("value", $(this).val() )
})
```

No need for the button to change the name of the table
fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/bqgqhxs2/2/